# extracting value from a file using ant

Tags: regex, ant

The following lines are present in the file. I would like to extract multiple data from this file.

> Number of current user build lists: 23
>
> - 'RevisionBuild' Run time (in minutes) = 8.40
>
> [Build] RC = 0

I used the following regex to retrieve the value 23 from this file

```
<ac:for param="line" list="${logFileContent}" delimiter="${line.separator}">
  <sequential>                          
<propertyregex property="noOfBuildlists"
         input="@{line}"
     regexp="(.*)Number of current user build lists: (.*)$"
     select="\2"/>  
  </sequential>
</ac:for>
```

But the same regex does not fetch any value when i try to fetch the other lines such as
regexp="(.*)[revBuild] RC = (.*)$" or regexp="(.*)'RevisionBuild' Run time (in minutes) = (.*)$" where the extracted values should be 0 and 8.40 respectively.

Can someone please help?
Thanks,
Aarthi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is what you are interested in. On an input file like below

```
Number of current user build lists: 23
'RevisionBuild' Run time (in minutes) = 8.40
[Build] RC = 0
```

when I execute below target

```
<project name="BuildModule" basedir="." default="extract.nums">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />
    <property environment="env" />
    <loadfile property="file" srcfile="${basedir}/inputLog.log"/>
    <target name="extract.nums">
        <for param="line" delimiter="${line.separator}" list="${file}">
            <sequential>
                <propertyregex property="noOfBuildlists" input="@{line}" regexp="Number of current user build lists:\s*([0-9]+)$" select="\1" />
                <propertyregex property="revisionBuild" input="@{line}" regexp="'RevisionBuild' Run time\s*\(in minutes\)\s*=\s*([0-9\.]+)$" select="\1" />
                <propertyregex property="rcBuild" input="@{line}" regexp="\[Build\] RC\s*\=\s*([0-9]+)$" select="\1" />
            </sequential>
        </for>
        <echo message="Current user build : ${noOfBuildlists}" />
        <echo message="Revision Build : ${revisionBuild}" />
        <echo message="RC Build : ${rcBuild}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

I get below output.

```
[echo] Current user build : 23
[echo] Revision Build : 8.40
[echo] RC Build : 0
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. This works very well. Can you please explain the usage of \s*. I notice that you use this regex everytime there is a space followed by a special character(such as ( or ) or =

Comment: `\s` represents whitespace character and `\s*` means zero or more occurrences for whitespace characters. This will make expression more robust and match even if there are more spaces or if there are none.

Comment: Thanks again Vaman. So in order to search a string "Does this buildlist need compile: true", I tried the following regex 
Does this buildlist need compile:\s*([r-t]+)$
However the regex does not work.

Comment: The reason your regex fails is `[r-t]+` means it will match characters between `r and t` i.e `rst`. You could use regex like this `Does this buildlist need compile:\s*(true|false)$`

Comment: HI Vaman,
Thanks again. My case is that I should count the number of occurances of the line "Does this buildlist need compile: true" in the file. I have opened another chain here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732509/how-to-use-ant-count-task-countfilter

Please help. Thanks Aarthi

Comment: Also, Ive tried the expressions "Does this buildlist need compile:\s*(true|false)$" and "Does this buildlist need compile:" where the count is correct. But when i change the expression to "Does this buildlist need compile:\s*(true)$", the count does not work.

Comment: What's the purpose of using `sequential` here?

Answer (score 1):

When I use `propertyregex`, it prompt an error `if doesn't support the nested "condition" element`. There are many nested "condition" element in my `{android.sdk.air}/tools/ant/build.xml`. So I tried to find a solution that standard Ant can present. I made it.

Try This:

```
<loadfile
    encoding="UTF-8"
    property="property.for.your.string"
    srcFile="your/file/path" >
        <filterchain>
            <tokenfilter>
                <containsregex
                    pattern="Number of current user build lists:\s*([0-9]+)$"
                    replace="\1" />
            </tokenfilter>
        </filterchain>
</loadfile>

<echo message="DEBUG LOG: property.for.your.string = ${property.for.your.string}" />
```

It makes me wonder why ant name the attribute as "replace", which leads to my misunderstanding.