# how to use ant count task countfilter

Tags: regex, ant

Im trying to count the number of occurences of the line "**Does this buildlist need compile: true**" in a file. I tried the following code, but it does not pick up the count

```
<concat>
<fileset file="@{logPathInTestSetup}" />
    <filterchain>
        <tokenfilter>
            <ct:countfilter property="noOfCompiledBuildlists" contains="Does this buildlist need compile:\s*(true)" override="true">
            <ct:counteach propertyprefix="count." select="\1" />
            </ct:countfilter>
         </tokenfilter>
         <ct:stopfilter />
      </filterchain>
</concat>
```

When I try counting "Does this buildlist need compile:", the counter works and I get the correct value. So there is definitely a problem with the regex. Can someone please help?
Thanks,
Aarthi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need some extra task, but Ant 1.7.1+  as `<concat>` has to be resource.
Here's a slightly adapted example from [ant manual resourcecount](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/resourcecount.html)
given input, foobar.txt :

```
Does this buildlist need compile: true
whatever
Does this buildlist need compile: false
The quick brown fox
jumps over the lazy dog
Does this buildlist need compile: true
Does this buildlist need compile: false
Does this buildlist need compile: true
foo
blablabla
Does this buildlist need compile: true
```

example ant script :

```
<project>
 <property name="file" value="foobar.txt"/>
  <resourcecount property="file.lines">
   <tokens>
    <concat>
     <filterchain>
      <linecontainsregexp>
       <regexp pattern="Does this buildlist need compile:\s*(true)"/>
      </linecontainsregexp>
     </filterchain>
     <fileset file="${file}"/>
    </concat>
   </tokens>
  </resourcecount>
  <echo>The file '${file}' has ${file.lines} lines.</echo>
</project>
```

output :

```
[echo] The file 'foobar.txt' has 4 lines.
```

**EDIT**
To get the lines that do not match, means negate your regex, simply use :

```
</linecontainsregexp negate="true">
```

Comment: Hi @Rebse, Can you please let me know how negation regex works. If I wanted to count lines that do not have "Does this buildlist need compile:\s*(true)", how can I do it?