# regex negation in ant

Tags: regex, ant, regex-negation, regex-greedy

Im trying to count the number of lines in a file that do not contain the following line:

```
/*================================================= */
```

or

```
Number of current users:
```

or 
an empty line

I am able to count the number of lines that do contain `LIB`,

```
<propertyregex property="noOfUsers"
               input="@{line}"
               regexp="Number of current users:\s*([0-9]+)$"
               select="\1" />
```

but, I can't derive the negation expression. Can someone please help me with this regex?

Comment: see this answer for solution => http://stackoverflow.com/a/11746966/130683

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use ant count task countfilter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732509/how-to-use-ant-count-task-countfilter)

Answer (score 1):

1. This is the pattern to find the commented line eg `/* anything * /`.Use this below pattern in your language and through loop u can find the no of commented lines.

   pattern: `/^[/][*].*[*][/]$/`
2. To find the empty lines you can use the below pattern

   pattern: `/^\n/`

Thanks,
Arun